# Cannot load postgis layer from sql string in pyqgis

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, pyqgis, sql

I'm trying to load a layer using the following code in qgis python console:

```
sql = "(select the_geom, ID from mytable)"
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("localhost","5432","mydb","postgres","XXXX")
uri.setDataSource("myschema",sql,"the_geom","","ID")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(),"LayerName","postgres")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

It doesn't add the layer but also doesn't return any error.

I'm using QGIS 2.4.0-Chugiak

Answer (score 2):

The postgres provider requires integer datatypes (i.e. ones, that are internally handled as `QVariant::Integer` or `QVariant::LongLong`)

Integer:

- int2
- int4

LongLong:

- int8

Comment: In that example says that there is an option like that: http://blog.georepublic.info/2013/joining-tables-with-sql-using-pyqgis/ I have already manage to load views or tables but I need to load layer from sql string. There is also another example here: http://carsonfarmer.com/2010/04/postgis-select-statement-as-vector-layer-in-qgis/

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Updated the answer.

Comment: Now I get: **Failed to load:unknown error**

Comment: What data type is the field `ID`?

Comment: I think that's the problem. The field is **character varying**. I check it with other data with **smallint** and it works. But the datasource should be "postgres" not "postgis", else it doesn't work. What are the appropriate data types? Is it possible to use a character varying field?

Comment: Sorry again for my repeated confusion. At the moment, only the key types listed in the answer are supported.

Comment: I did `CAST(coalesce(ID, 0) AS integer) as ID` to cast to integer and now it works fine. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Also, the code works only if I don't define schema in DataSource:`uri.setDataSource("",sql,"the_geom","","ID")`