# How to load the only selected features from the layer in postgresql to Qgis canvas

Tags: postgresql, pyqgis

I am using the uri to load the layer from the postgres to qgis canvas but it is not loading the selected features without where condition it is loading the lAYER.

```
    canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
    csql='ST_Intersects("p1".geom, "p2".geom)'
    uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
    uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "ZBE", "postgres", "postgres")
    uri.setDataSource("public","Sample", "geom",csql,"dn")
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "test", "postgres") 
    if not vlayer.isValid():
        print "not valid"
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
    canvas.refresh()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but it looks to me that your `csql` should be something like:

```
csql='SELECT field1,field2,etc 
  FROM "Trainingset" t, "Polygon" p 
  WHERE ST_Intersects(t.geom, p.geom)'
```

Comment: actually we have to give where condition only in sql part i uri.datasource. http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html?highlight=postgres

Comment: Did you try ? You can't use only "where" clause with 2 tables.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112409/cannot-load-postgis-layer-from-sql-string-in-pyqgis

Comment: no i have tried that but it didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little trick here. You are in a WHERE clause. To query more than one table, you can use a subquery. Suppose you have the tables *p1* and *p2* from the same PostGIS database, both with the field *id* as a primary key. You want to filter *p1* in QGIS to show only *p1* features that intersect *p2* features. Try:

```
csql = "p1.id IN (SELECT p1.id FROM p1, p2 WHERE ST_Intersects(p1.geom, p2.geom))"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find another solution for this, consider creating a `VIEW` in PostgreSQL and then add that as a layer. This has the added benefit that you can change the query in the database without touching your Python code. (So, for example, if you have several users using QGIS with this code installed, you can update all of them immediately by updating the server.)

The syntax for the view is something like,

```
CREATE VIEW boo AS SELECT * FROM p1, p2 WHERE ST_Intersects(p1.geom, p2.geom)
```

Then just use `boo` as the table name in the Python script, and leave out the SQL.